# no icon for alert dialog

Tags: android

even if I don't set icon `.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)` for dialog box, it is showing info icon.

How can I completely remove the icon from dialog box?

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)
    .setTitle(R.string.success_title)
    .setMessage(R.string.success_msg)
    .setNeutralButton("OK",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
                try {
                    dlg.dismiss();
                } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
}).show();
```

Edited: 
Sorry everyone.. I completely remove .setIcon line from the dialog box. I forget to remove it when I paste the code here. Even I remove that I still can see the icon as information icon.

Answer (score 6):

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)
    //.setIcon(android.R.drawable.i)    /// put comment on this line
    .setTitle(R.string.success_title)
    .setMessage(R.string.success_msg)
    .setNeutralButton("OK",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
                try 
                {
                    dlg.dismiss();
                } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
}).show();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try This

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
    .setIcon(null)
    .setTitle("Naeem").setMessage("Shahzad").setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) {
            try {
                dlg.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }).show();
```

Comment: Which android version you are working on. I have tested this code working fine on Android 4.1.

Comment: I have tested on 4.0.3 and it was working fine too. maybe you can test on some other device to verify. I have verified on two more devices and it was working like charm.

Answer (score 1):

Set resId to 0 in `setIcon(int resId)` of your *AlertDialog.Builder* object.

Comment: Still information icon. Testing version is android 7 api 24.